# Google Charts cache geocoding requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, google-visualization

I'm using the [Geochart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) of Google Charts in a Dashboard. Every time the dashboard gets loaded Google geocodes the cities. Is it possible to use some kind of caching to speed up the whole process? The cities seem to get geocoded one by one. Takes some time.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you may avoid the geocoding when you know the LatLng of a address, use the first 2 columns to define latitude and longitude, e.g.:

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['lat'    ,'lng'      ,'City',  'Population','Area'],
    [41.872388, 12.480180 ,'Rome',  2761477     ,1285.31],
    [45.465421, 9.185924  ,'Milan', 1324110     ,181.76]
  ]);
```

But AFAIK the geocoded LatLng's (automatically geocoded by the chart-API) are not accessible, so you must request some geocoding-service to get these LatLng's to be able to store them.

Note: when you use the google-geocoder you are only allowed to store these data temporarily

Comment: It worked perfectly for my project. Thank you, Dr.Molle!

https://jpbarbosa.github.io/japan/